# Arguments overridden in managed callable tasks in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have several container managed callable tasks that are invoked with `invokeAll`. I need to pass arguments to each of these tasks, and since I'm getting instances instead of creating objects manually (this is a requirement) I cannot pass arguments in a constructor.

I'm using setters in the task to set values, but for some reason when I have multiple tasks the last value overrides the previous one.

Given this task:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyTask implements Callable<String> {

    private String value;

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("MyTask called with value = " + value);
        return "MyTask called";
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Called with this `Test` class:

```
public class Test {

    @Inject
    Instance<MyTask> myTaskInstance;

    @Resource
    private ManagedExecutorService executor;

    public void test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        List<Callable<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<>(); 

        MyTask task1 = myTaskInstance.get();
        task1.setValue("VAL1");
        tasks.add(task1);

        MyTask task2 = myTaskInstance.get();
        task2.setValue("VAL2");
        tasks.add(task2);

        List<Future<String>> taskResults = null;
        taskResults = executor.invokeAll(tasks);

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>(); 

        for(Future<String> taskResult : taskResults) {
                results.add(taskResult.get());
        }

    }

}
```

The result is (note `VAL2` twice):

> 13:04:49,044 INFO  [stdout]
>   (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-3) MyTask called with value
>   = VAL2
>
> 13:04:49,045 INFO  [stdout]
>   (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-4) MyTask called with value
>   = VAL2

What is wrong with this code? How to fix this?

**UPDATE**
After changing the bean to `@Stateful` these are the task instances right before `invokeAll`

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems as though `myTaskInstance.get()` is returning the same instance on every call, rather than a new instance.

Comment: shouldn't it return a different instance?

Comment: The documentation for `Provider<T>#get`, which `Instance<T>` implements, states *"Provides a fully-constructed and injected instance of T."* Which makes me think it only returns instances that have been injected.

Comment: What I don't get is why would the container reuse the instance if the first one is still in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly normal.

A `@Stateless` bean is created in multiple instances, depending on your server pool configuration.
So the same instance is re-used from the pool.

Per definition a `@Stateless` bean **cannot** maintain a state.
Use a `@Stateful` bean instead.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189631/discussion-on-answer-by-lppedd-arguments-overridden-in-managed-callable-tasks-in).